# QFT Scattering Amplitude ——What does Vol(GL(k)) mean?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I'm self-studying the momentum twistor stuff for scattering amplitude and keep seeing  $\frac{1}{Vol(GL(k))}$ in the integral. I know this term is for gauge fixing but I have only read some introductory notes about gauge theory so I have no clue what that is and how it works. I know the GL groups but I don't understand  what the volume means. Can anyone explain what $Vol(GL(k))$ stands for explicitly, or refer me some books? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add a link or a reference to the material that you are reading.

Answer (score 3):

${\rm Vol}(G)$ presumably means the volume of a Lie group $G$ viewed as a differential manifold with some pertinent volume form. Since the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL(k)$ of $k\times k$ matrices is non-compact, the volume is infinite.